# Uploading large files using angular and Ionic

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ionic-framework, file-upload, angular9

In our Ionic mobile application we have implemented Image Upload. This works fine for smaller images but not for large images. For e.g. more than 5 MB.

We are executing the APIs from angular and APIs are written in .Net Core.

We have used capacitor plugin to read the images and also, we have resized to 50% before executing the API. The images is passed in Base64 format to API. Along with Images we are sending form data also.

The problem here is, the request itself is NOT going to API. The APIs are hosted in AWS having IIS Server.

Only sometimes we are getting error 204 No Content. But, we are still not sure about this.

Below is the code written in Angular.

```
CreateFormData(data) {
const jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
return this.http.post(`${this.rootApi}${ApiEndpointUrls.saveform}`, jsondata, this.headers).pipe(
timeout(15000),
tap(async (res) => {
})
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if you can modify this on an AWS setups.. but have you looked at maxRequestLength in the web.config..

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="9000" />
```